# Does NSJSONSerialization have a maximum parse depth?

Tags: json, cocoa, nsjsonserialization

When using `SBJson` in the past, I reached the [maximum parse depth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11854635/parsing-json-reached-max-depth) and had to increase the limit.

Now I'm moving to using Apple's built in `NSJSONSerialization`, and wondering whether it has a hidden limit that's outside of our control?